# WSO2 ESB & SSL/IIS - Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service

Tags: iis, ssl, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I created a proxy service using WSO2 ESB to deal with a secured IIS WS.
I am pretty sure that I configured correctly the ESB SSL settings : customSSLProfiles, policy, keystore, truststore

But I am facing the obscure error : Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.
And here is my wso2carbon.log :

```
DEBUG - ServerHandler HTTP connection [13.12.11.10/13.12.11.10:56590]: Connected
DEBUG - ServerHandler Adding a connection : [13.12.11.10/13.12.11.10:56590] to the pool, existing pool size : 0
DEBUG - wire >> "POST /services/Proxy.ProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "SOAPAction: "http://s"[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Length: 2717[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "Host: 13.12.11.10:8243[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - headers >> POST /services/Proxy.ProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint HTTP/1.1
DEBUG - headers >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
DEBUG - headers >> Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
DEBUG - headers >> SOAPAction: "urn:mediate"
DEBUG - headers >> Content-Length: 2717
DEBUG - headers >> Host: 13.12.11.10:8243
DEBUG - headers >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG - headers >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
DEBUG - access 13.12.11.10:8243 - - - "POST /services/Proxy.ProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
DEBUG - ServerHandler HTTP connection [13.12.11.10/13.12.11.10:56590]: POST /services/Proxy.ProxyHttpsSoap11Endpoint HTTP/1.1
DEBUG - ServerHandler HTTP connection [13.12.11.10/13.12.11.10:56590]: Input ready
DEBUG - ServerHandler HTTP connection [13.12.11.10/13.12.11.10:56590]: Content decoder [content length: 2717; pos: 0; completed: false]
DEBUG - ServerHandler HTTP connection [13.12.11.10/13.12.11.10:56590]: Input ready
DEBUG - wire >> "<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">[\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "<s:Body Id="id"><tag xmlns="urn:mine" ></tag></s:Body></s:Envelope>[\n]"
DEBUG - ServerHandler HTTP connection [13.12.11.10/13.12.11.10:56590]: Content decoder [content length: 2717; pos: 2717; completed: true]
 INFO - TimeoutHandler This engine will expire all callbacks after : 86400 seconds, irrespective of the timeout action, after the specified or optional timeout
DEBUG - ConnectionPool No connections available for reuse
DEBUG - HttpCoreNIOSender A new connection established to : iisserver:443
DEBUG - Axis2HttpRequest Start streaming outgoing http request : [Message ID : urn:uuid:d5daaf37-53f2-4841-b20a-12133337ddca]
DEBUG - HttpCoreNIOSender Connected to remote address : iisserver/1.11.111.0:443 from local address : /13.12.11.10:56591
DEBUG - ClientHandler HTTP connection [iisserver/1.11.111.0:443]: Connected (Axis2Request [Message ID : urn:uuid:d5daaf37-53f2-4841-b20a-12133337ddca] [Status Completed : false] [Status SendingCompleted : false])
DEBUG - ClientHandler ClientHandler connected : [iisserver/1.11.111.0:443]
DEBUG - headers >> POST /partner/Service.svc HTTP/1.1
DEBUG - headers >> Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
DEBUG - headers >> Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
DEBUG - headers >> SOAPAction: "http://s"
DEBUG - headers >> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
DEBUG - headers >> Host: iisserver:443
DEBUG - headers >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG - headers >> User-Agent: Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO
DEBUG - wire << "POST /partner/Service.svc HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "SOAPAction: "http://s"[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "Host: iisserver:443[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "User-Agent: Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - ClientHandler HTTP connection [iisserver/1.11.111.0:443]: Output ready [Request Message ID : urn:uuid:d5daaf37-53f2-4841-b20a-12133337ddca]
DEBUG - ClientHandler HTTP connection [iisserver/1.11.111.0:443]: Content encoder [chunk-coded; completed: true]
DEBUG - wire << "186e[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" s:actor="IntervenantEmetteur"><wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-1"><wsu:Created>2012-10-04T19:11:54.357Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2012-10-04T19:16:54.357Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-2">[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:SignedInfo>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:Reference URI="#id">[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:Transforms>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:Transforms>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:DigestValue>mp/vvvvvvvv=</ds:DigestValue>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:Reference>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:Reference URI="#Timestamp-1">[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:Transforms>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:Transforms>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:DigestValue>F/vvvvvvvvvvv=</ds:DigestValue>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:Reference>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:SignedInfo>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:SignatureValue>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/FwQC[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "H7wOwMRUsv9BpvxYGVw=[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:SignatureValue>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-9C7C8315814519AAFA13493779144122">[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:X509Data>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:X509SubjectName>CN=sipmiesbdev,OU=INSPQ,O=INSPQ,L=Qu[0xc3][0xa9]bec,ST=Qu[0xc3][0xa9]bec,C=CA</ds:X509SubjectName>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "<ds:X509Certificate>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY==[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:X509Certificate>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:X509Data>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:KeyInfo>[\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "</ds:Signature></wsse:Security></s:Header><s:Body Id="id"><tag xmlns="urn:mine"></tag></s:Body></s:Envelope>[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "0[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - ClientHandler HTTP connection [iisserver/1.11.111.0:443]: Request ready [Request Message ID : urn:uuid:d5daaf37-53f2-4841-b20a-12133337ddca]
DEBUG - wire >> "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Length: 131[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Type: text/html[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "Date: Thu, 04 Oct 2012 19:11:56 GMT[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.[\r][\n]"
DEBUG - wire >> "</body></html>"
DEBUG - headers << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
DEBUG - headers << Content-Length: 131
DEBUG - headers << Content-Type: text/html
DEBUG - headers << Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
DEBUG - headers << X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
DEBUG - headers << Date: Thu, 04 Oct 2012 19:11:56 GMT
DEBUG - ClientHandler HTTP connection [iisserver/1.11.111.0:443] : HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error [Request Message ID : urn:uuid:d5daaf37-53f2-4841-b20a-12133337ddca]
DEBUG - ClientHandler Response Received for Request : Axis2Request [Message ID : urn:uuid:d5daaf37-53f2-4841-b20a-12133337ddca] [Status Completed : true] [Status SendingCompleted : true]
 WARN - ClientHandler Received an internal server error : Internal Server Error For : 1.11.111.0:443 For Request : Axis2Request [Message ID : urn:uuid:d5daaf37-53f2-4841-b20a-12133337ddca] [Status Completed : true] [Status SendingCompleted : true]
DEBUG - ClientHandler HTTP connection [iisserver/1.11.111.0:443]: Input ready [Request Message ID : urn:uuid:d5daaf37-53f2-4841-b20a-12133337ddca]
DEBUG - ConnectionPool Released a connection to host: iisserver on port : 443 to the connection pool of current size : 1
DEBUG - ClientHandler HTTP connection [iisserver/1.11.111.0:443]: Content decoder [content length: 131; pos: 131; completed: true]
 INFO - BuilderUtil OMException in getSOAPBuilder
 INFO - BuilderUtil Remaining input stream :[]
 WARN - ClientWorker Unexpected response received. HTTP response code : 500 HTTP status : Internal Server Error exception : First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
DEBUG - ClientWorker Unexpected response received. HTTP response code : 500 HTTP status : Internal Server Error exception : First Element must contain the local name, Envelope , but found html
DEBUG - ClientWorker Creating the SOAPFault to be injected...
ERROR - AxisEngine Missing wsse:Security header in request
 WARN - ClientWorker Fault processing response message through Axis2: Missing wsse:Security header in request
DEBUG - ClientWorker Fault processing response message through Axis2: Missing wsse:Security header in request
DEBUG - ClientWorker Directly invoking SynapseCallbackReceiver after setting error properties
DEBUG - access iisserver:443 - - - "POST /partner/Service.svc HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "Synapse-HttpComponents-NIO"
DEBUG - access -  - Thu, 04 Oct 2012 19:11:56 GMT "- - " 500 - "-" "-"
DEBUG - ServerHandler HTTP connection [closed]: Closed
DEBUG - ServerHandler Removing the connection : [closed] from pool of size : 0
DEBUG - ClientHandler HTTP connection [closed]: Closed
DEBUG - ClientHandler Keep-alive connection closed For : 1.11.111.0:443
DEBUG - ClientHandler Connection to remote address : iisserver/1.11.111.0:443 from local address : /13.12.11.10:56591 is closed!
```

As you see, the ESB signes my message, but when sending it, the error occurs : a quite instantaneous HTTP 500 response.

Notwithstanding, I get the expected reponse when I request the IIS WS using a SOAP client using the ESB-signed message with same headers.

Please, can you shed some light on this issue, I am stuck here for a couple of days, your help will be greatly appreciated

Many thanks, 
Med

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about chunked transfer encoding !

See : 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SYNAPSE-915